# Entity Framework dynamic Table Names or alternatives

Tags: .net, entity-framework

we are using Entity Framework for a client who wants to retrieve data from a database. Until now, everything was easy and straightforward.

However, now the requirements changed. We need the same type data, i.e. the same Models, but the data should change based on the project the whole context is needed for. More or less like this:

A user creates a new project, named `project1`. The Models for EF are called `Category` and `Item`, for instance. His data should reside in the tables `project1_categories` and `project1_items`. He then creates a new project `project2` and now we need new tables called `project2_categories` and `project2_items`, but backed by the same model.

We can't use the Fluent API's `OnModelCreating` to map the model to a table, because the instance of DbContext will always be the same. The projects the users can create will be dynamic, so we need dynamic table names.

Should we switch to a different ORM? Or is it possible to use EF? We would really appreciatenot having to switch to a different ORM Framework just for this.

As a bonus, currently our data is displayed in a WPF application. We directly bind the Local property (`ObservableCollection<T>`) to the Views, this way, EF handles all the data changes automatically and we just need to call `SaveChanges`. Would be great if this could be preserved.

Comment: I'm confused as to why do you even need the new tables for every project, when adding a "projects" table and adding the id column from that table as fk column in categories and items would suffice.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, I know and I would love to make it that way. But unfortunately, we have to do what our Client wants. Different Tables...